# Javascript: Easiest way to make a list of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div and a list with some items in it:

```
<div id="myDiv">
<ul>
    <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

How could I easily make a Javascript array of the 'a' elements knowing that the number of items may change?

Comment: _"knowing that the number of items may change"_ - Do you mean you want the array to automatically update if anchor elements are added or removed after the page loads? Or just that you won't know in advance how many there are?

Comment: The page may add more elements to this list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a static list:

```
var mylist = $('#myDiv > ul > li > a').toArray();
```

---

But you wrote *"...knowing that the number of items may change"*. If this means you want a "live list" that updates with DOM changes, then do this:

```
var mylivelist = document.getElementById("myDiv")
                         .getElementsByTagName("a");
```

This list will update when items are added or removed. It makes the assumption that there are no other `<a>` elements in the `<div>`. If there are, you'll need to adjust.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery then it's

```
$('#myDiv a')
```

if no jQuery then just this

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').getElementsByTagName('a')
```

Comment: Both methods don't return an array though.

Comment: True, the jquery one doesn't, but you can stick .toArray() on the end of it.

Comment: The second doesn't either, it's a `DOMNodeList`.

Answer (score 0):

In plain old javascript (no jQuery needed):

```
    var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    var allAnchors = myDiv.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < allAnchors.length; i++) {
        //do something with each allAnchors[i] node
        document.write(allAnchors[i].innerHTML + '<br />');
    }
```